# easyphp 17 (devserver) and module

Tags: easyphp

)

Updates are available, you think soon provide a new version for at least some modules?

Codiad 2.8.4
phpMyAdmin 4.7.9
Apache 2.4.33
MySQL 5.7.21
Xdebug Manager 2.6.0
php 7.2.4
php 7.1.16
php 7.0.29
php 5.6.35

cordially Franck

Answer (score 0):

FYI, PhpMyAdmin 4.8.0 is available.